# Opening database created in a new instance of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have installed a new instance of SQL Server to restore a database I have. I have also set user authorization by creating user login and have set password (SQL Server authentication mode). However at-last after restoring database, there was no security to my database, client browsed the location on database file and was able to view my queries !

[image]

Is there any method to stop this access of database ?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you tag C# for this

Comment: What kind of privileges does the Client have on this instance? I am guessing SA

Comment: @RahulNikate thank you for reviewing that tag,it was by mistake,i have corrected

Comment: There you go. SA is like God for the instance. You cannot prevent SA from accessing any DB you create on the instance.

Comment: so how to resolve the issue ? please help me out ..

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to [disable SA account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642673/can-i-remove-sa-login-from-sql-server), but I really don't recommend it. SA stands for System Administrator, and every system needs one.
it's good practice to rename it and give it a strong password, and **never** share it's login details with anyone other your dba.
setup a new sql server account for your client, with as little privileges as possible.

Comment: thank you @ZoharPeled but i can view the database in folder know?and does it prevent client from attaching in his system ?

Comment: does your client connect to your server, or does he works on a local (i mean, in his system) file based database?

Comment: actually network with server and multiple clients accessing one main server

Comment: Ok, so your clients can`t see the file system on the server, right? all they have is the connection string. giving them the minimal privileges will solve your problem with them. [read this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497471/protecting-sql-server-database-file) to see how can you protect the database files.

Comment: thank you for your response but the server system is accessed by one client system which is admin/supervisor

Comment: Well, if you can't trust your admin, who can you trust? someone has to have access to the file system, if it's not you then it should be someone you can trust.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77481/discussion-between-utility-and-zohar-peled).